# Chromium and Firefox slow after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: networking, firefox, chromium, thunderbird

I have re-installed from 18.04 after using 14.04. Now, Chrome and Firefox can take ages to connect to sites, and sometimes fail with a socket error. Running speed tests, they start off ok, but reruns get progressively slower until the socket fault occurs. I think also Thunderbird may be slower at contacting the server. Other machines, connecting through the same wifi modem are ok. Any suggestions please?
Tony